# gcc static analyzer (Weffc++): exclude directories

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, static-analysis, software-quality

I have a big project that uses many, many libraries. Some of them are HDF5, PugiXML, Boost.ASIO, Qt, MuParser, and many others. Some of these libraries are included by header, and some are pre-compiled, and some of them I compiled myself. I'd like to use the gcc option `-Weffc++` to ensure the quality of my code.

The problem is that I got over 2000 warnings when I enabled that option, and when I went quickly through the list, there was like 1 of them related to my project, and almost everything else was from the headers I included! It's very not practical to go through the whole list. Is there a way to tell gcc to either analyze files from given directories, or exclude directies in some way (regex maybe?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments in the documentation are not good news:

> When selecting this option, be aware that the standard library headers do not obey all of these guidelines; use ‘grep -v’ to filter out those warnings.

You can disable the warning temporarily with pragmas:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Weffc++"
#include <header1>
#include <header2>
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
```

You might also be able to use `-isystem` to specify include paths, which suppresses certain warnings from files included through those paths.

### Recommendation

Just don't use `-Weffc++`.  It gives garbage even in your own project.  For example, it will ask you to define virtual destructors for *all* base classes, regardless of whether that makes even a small amount of sense.  It will warn if you don't initialize every member in aggregate initialization.  After throwing my hands in the air and saying, "That warning is just stupid!" for the hundredth time, I turned `-Weffc++` off and moved on with my life.

There are much better tools out there for code quality and enforcing style.  Clang tools like `clang-tidy`, `clang-modernize`, and `clang-format` come to minde.

Comment: Actually, I'm just realizing that some warnings are stupid... the problem is that I'm using Qt, and I can't use clang unless I recompile the whole Qt library. I'm trying to see whether I could use clang without that hassle.

Comment: `clang` is not the same thing as `clang-tidy`.  `clang-tidy` is not a compiler, it is a separate code analysis tool.  You don't have to recompile anything.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for the info. I'll check that.

Comment: @The Quantum Physicist It's perfectly possible to build a project that uses Qt with clang even if Qt was compiled with gcc.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Actually I don't know how to switch to clang while using Qt (qmake). Would you tell me how to do that or refer me to some reference? The difficulty for me is that the compiler name (compile command) is set in `qmakespec` when Qt is compiled. I don't understand how a switch is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify directories with `-isystem` to avoid the `-Weffc++` processing on those directories. This works even when they have been specified earlier with `-I`.